# Spring MVC disable back button action after logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I used the following bean for the browser not to be able to go back after logout

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

in Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE this class is deprecated So i used the following

```
@Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {

        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter rmha = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        rmha.setCacheSecondsForSessionAttributeHandlers(0);

        return rmha;
    }
```

But I am unable to stop the back button action. what i mean is its going back the page after logout.

Where am i making mistake??
How to fix this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cacheSeconds` is an inherited method coming from [WebContentGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/WebContentGenerator.html#setCacheSeconds%28int%29).

This is the case for both `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

So all you have to do is call the right method as you were calling before:

```
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter rmha = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
rmha.setCacheSeconds(0);
```